# How to return two things in a Flask directory

Tags: python, flask

Title pretty much explains it, here's my current code:

```
from flask import Flask
import random
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    name = ('qwerty', 'uiopa', 'sdfgh', 'jklzx', 'cvbnm')
    named = (random.choice(name))
    return  named, "<img src='https://picsum.photos/800/450'>" # This only returns named
```

I've also tried:

```
return  named; "<img src='https://picsum.photos/800/450'>" # This only returns named

return  "{{ named }} <img src='https://picsum.photos/800/450'>" # This returns as "{{ named}}" and then the image instead of actually giving me the variable itself

return named and "<img src='https://picsum.photos/800/450'>" # this only gives me the image
```

Comment: `return  f"{named} <img src='https://picsum.photos/800/450'>"` - use formatted string to put in the value.

Comment: ...unless you're trying to return some other format e.g. json, in which case return that, or a dict.  But I guess you're just trying to get a named image here.

Answer (score 0):

Bon by looking at your question I think you are trying to pass the image and its name on the web page. You can do it by rendering a template

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
def index():
    name = ('qwerty', 'uiopa', 'sdfgh', 'jklzx', 'cvbnm')
    named = (random.choice(name))
    img="image path"
    result={'img':img,'name':named}
    return render_template("result.html",result = result)
```

Your result.html will be like

```
<!doctype html>
  <table border = 1>

    <tr>
       <th> {{ result.name }} </th>
       <img src="{{ result.img }}">  </img>
    </tr>

 </table>
```

That's How you will be able to pass more than one value with a dictionary. Hope it will be helpful.